# Why is this not reported as an issue by ASAN as stack-use-after-scope?

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

I am not able to understand the concept behind Address Sanitizer - (stack-use-after-scope).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class User {
        public:
        User(){
                _name = "No Name";
        }
        User(string name){
                _name = name;
                _salary = 0;
        }

        string getName(){
                return _name;
        }

        int* getRoles(){
                return _roles;
        }
        private:
        string _name;
        int _salary;
        int _roles[5];
};

class Employee {
        public:
        Employee(User user){
                _user = user;
        }

        User getUser(){
                return _user;
        }
        private:
        User _user;

};
int main() {
        // your code goes here

        User user("User1");
        Employee employee(user);

        auto roles = employee.getUser().getRoles();
        roles[0] = 1;
}
```

Here from what I understand getUser returns a temporary object that might be destroyed and the roles variable might point to a loation already reclaimed. Is that understanding correct?

Similarly the folowing code gives error.

```
string name = "name123";
auto arr = name.substr(0,4).c_str();
cout<<arr[0];
```

But why not this?

```
string name = "name123";
string sub(name.substr(0,4).c_str());
cout<<sub;
```

Comment: `string sub(name.substr(0,4).c_str());` creates a new string, where do you expect an error to happen here?

Comment: `string sub(name.substr(0,4).c_str());` does **not** have *stack use after scope*.  As a result, ASan does not report stack use after scope for that one.

Comment: `getUser` returns a temporary which, as described by [temporary object lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime), is destroyed at the end of the full-expression. That's at the `;`, not part-way through.

Comment: I am assuming name.substr(0,4); would return a temporary object, would it's lifecycle end after object initialization or before? is it because temporary objects live through out the expression?

Comment: It's another temporary, so it also lives to the end of the full-expression - ie, it isn't destroyed until after the `string` has been constructed.

Comment: You know you can check all this stuff with a little class that logs from its destructor and constructors? It's very easy to test your intuition and see exactly what happens.

Comment: It's about when the temporary is destroyed. I believe it is destroyed after the statement it is used in. If that is true, then in the second example it'd be alive until after the constructor is done

Comment: if this wouldnt work then method chaining with values would be impossible.

Comment: Your question is irrelevant to any C++ version, why have you spammed with two versions, cannot decide which one to use?

Comment: Totally unrelated: Read up on the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). Save you a bit of coring time, often quite a bit of runtime, and make more complicated base classes and members possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Temporary objects persist until the end of the full expression in which they're created.  A full expression is an expression that isn't part of another expression, so basically until the next `;`.

That means that in this snippet

```
auto arr = name.substr(0,4).c_str();
cout<<arr[0];
```

`arr` is a pointer to the array owned by the temporary object returned by `substr`.  Since that object gets destroyed at the end of the full expression in which it's created, it no longer exists when you attempt to read from it in the next statement.

---

In this statement

```
string sub(name.substr(0,4).c_str());
cout<<sub;
```

The array pointed to by the pointer returned by `c_str` continues to exist until the end of the full expression.  That means it's still alive when `sub`'s constructor accesses it to copy its contents.

The temporary string has been destroyed by the time the `cout` statement runs, but that doesn't matter anymore, since `sub` is still alive and contains a copy of the data from the temporary object.